# DB2 V9 ZOS - Performance tuning

Tags: db2, zos

## Background

Currently I am using DB2 V9 version.  One of my stored procedure is taking time to execute.  I looked BMC apptune and found the following SQL.
There are three tables we were using to execute the following query.
ACCOUNT table is having 3413 records
EXCHANGE_RATE is having 1267K records
BALANCE is having 113M records

Someone has added recently following piece of code in the query.  I think because of this we had a problem.

```
AND (((A.ACT <> A.EW_ACT)             
      AND (A.EW_ACT <> ' ')                    
      AND (C.ACT = A.EW_ACT))         
     OR (C.ACT = A.ACT))
```

## Query

```
SELECT F1.CLO_LED                               
INTO :H :H  
FROM (SELECT A.ACT, A.BNK, A.ACT_TYPE,                                  
             CASE WHEN :H = A.CUY_TYPE THEN DEC(C.CLO_LED, 21, 2)                 
             ELSE DEC(MULTIPLY_ALT(C.CLO_LED, COALESCE(B.EXC_RATE, 0)), 21, 2)         
             END AS CLO_LED                           
      FROM ACCOUNT A                             
      LEFT OUTER JOIN EXCHANGE_RATE B                 
      ON B.EFF_DATE = CURRENT DATE - 1 DAY         
      AND B.CURCY_FROM  = A.CURNCY_TYPE       
      AND B.CURCY_TO = :H          
      AND B.STA_TYPE = 'A'                   
        , BALANCE C                           
      WHERE A.CUSR_ID = :DCL.CUST-ID   
      AND A.ACT = :DCL.ACT
      AND A.EIG_RTN = :WS-BNK-ID                  
      AND A.ACT_TYPE = :DCL.ACT-TYPE    
      AND A.ACT_CAT = :DCL.ACT-CAT 
      AND A.STA_TYPE = 'A'                      
      AND (((A.ACT <> A.EW_ACT)             
            AND (A.EW_ACT <> ' ')                    
            AND (C.ACT = A.EW_ACT))         
           OR (C.ACT = A.ACT))                
      AND C.BNK =  :WS-BNK-ID                
      AND C.ACT_TYPE = :DCL.ACT-TYPE  
      AND C.BUS_DATE = :WS-DATE-FROM) F1                                              
WITH UR
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a number of wierd things going on in this query.  The most twitchy of which is mixing explicit joins with the implicit-join syntax; frankly, I'm not certain how the system interprets it.  You also appear to be using the same host-variable for both input and output; please don't.
Also, why are your column names so short?  DB2 (that version, at least) supports column names that are much longer.  Please save people's sanity, if at all possible.

We can't completely say why things are slow - we may need to see access plans.  In the meantime, here's your query, restructured to what *may* be a faster form:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN :inputType = a.cuy_type THEN DEC(b.clo_led, 21, 2)
            ELSE DEC(MULTIPLY_ALT(b.clo_led, COALESCE(c.exc_rate, 0)), 21, 2) END
INTO :amount :amountIndicator  -- if you get results, do you need the indiciator?
FROM Account as a
JOIN Balance as b  -- This is assumed to not be a 'left', given coalesce not used
ON b.bnk = a.eig_rtn
AND b.act_type = a.act_type
AND b.bus_date = :ws-date-from
AND ((a.act <> a.ew_act     -- something feels wrong here, but
      AND a.ew_act <> ' '   -- without knowing the data, I don't
      AND c.act = a.ew_act) -- want to muck with it.
     OR c.act = a.act)
LEFT JOIN Exchange_Rate as c
ON c.eff_date = current_date - 1 day
AND c.curcy_from = a.curncy_type
AND c.sta_type = a.sta_type
AND c.curcy_to = :destinationCurrency
WHERE a.cusr_id = :dcl.cust-id
AND a.act = :dcl.act
AND a.eig_rtn = :ws-bnk-id
AND a.act_type = :dcl.act-type
AND a.act_cat = :dcl.act-cat
AND a.sta_type = 'A'
WITH UR
FECTCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

A few other notes:

1. Only specify *exactly* those columns needed - under certain circumstances, this permits index-only access, where otherwise a followup table-access may be needed.  However, this probably won't help here.
2. `COALESCE(c.exc_rate, 0)` feels off somehow - if no exchange rate is present, you return an amount of `0`, which could otherwise be a *valid* amount.  You may need to return some sort of indicator, or make it a normal join, not an outer one.

Also, try both this version, and possibly a version where host variables are specified *in addition to* the conditions between tables.  The optimizer should be able to automatically commute the values, but may not under some conditions (implementation detail).